# How could I graphically display the memory layout from a .map file?

Tags: c++, c, linker

My gcc build toolchain produces a .map file. How do I display the memory sections using memory map graphically?

Comment: I am really interested in this question. Was hoping you would get some nice answers. But maybe everyone like me only upvoting your question and waiting :) Stay tuned.. Cheers - Prakash

Comment: Given a list of (address, symbol type, symbol name) tuples from a map file, it's not immediately obvious what types of graphs could be constructed.  Could you revise the question to explain what you'd like to visualize?

Comment: try this one: http://www.absint.com/stackanalyzer/ i dont use GCC so I really cant answer but thought the link might be what you are after.

Comment: I don't see why this was closed.  There are no comments indicating the questions lack of focus and the question is very specific.  "How to view a map file graphicaly".  the question should be reopened.

Comment: I can't add this answer as the question is closed but this tool does the job: https://www.sikorskiy.net/info/prj/amap/

Comment: Also this: https://github.com/PromyLOPh/linkermapviz

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's the beginnings of a script in Python. It loads the map file into a list of Sections and Symbols (first half). It then renders the map using HTML (or do whatever you want with the `sections` and `symbols` lists).

You can control the script by modifying these lines:

```
with open('t.map') as f:
colors = ['9C9F84', 'A97D5D', 'F7DCB4', '5C755E']
total_height = 32.0
```

map2html.py

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import re

class Section:
    def __init__(self, address, size, segment, section):
        self.address = address
        self.size = size
        self.segment = segment
        self.section = section
    def __str__(self):
        return self.section+""

class Symbol:
    def __init__(self, address, size, file, name):
        self.address = address
        self.size = size
        self.file = file
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

#===============================
# Load the Sections and Symbols
#
sections = []
symbols = []

with open('t.map') as f:
    in_sections = True
    for line in f:
        m = re.search('^([0-9A-Fx]+)\s+([0-9A-Fx]+)\s+((\[[ 0-9]+\])|\w+)\s+(.*?)\s*$', line)
        if m:
            if in_sections:
                sections.append(Section(eval(m.group(1)), eval(m.group(2)), m.group(3), m.group(5)))
            else:
                symbols.append(Symbol(eval(m.group(1)), eval(m.group(2)), m.group(3), m.group(5)))
        else:
            if len(sections) > 0:
                in_sections = False


#===============================
# Gererate the HTML File
#

colors = ['9C9F84', 'A97D5D', 'F7DCB4', '5C755E']
total_height = 32.0

segments = set()
for s in sections: segments.add(s.segment)
segment_colors = dict()
i = 0
for s in segments:
    segment_colors[s] = colors[i % len(colors)]
    i += 1

total_size = 0
for s in symbols:
    total_size += s.size

sections.sort(lambda a,b: a.address - b.address)
symbols.sort(lambda a,b: a.address - b.address)

def section_from_address(addr):
    for s in sections:
        if addr >= s.address and addr < (s.address + s.size):
            return s
    return None

print "<html><head>"
print "  <style>a { color: black; text-decoration: none; font-family:monospace }</style>"
print "<body>"
print "<table cellspacing='1px'>"
for sym in symbols:
    section = section_from_address(sym.address)
    height = (total_height/total_size) * sym.size
    font_size = 1.0 if height > 1.0 else height
    print "<tr style='background-color:#%s;height:%gem;line-height:%gem;font-size:%gem'><td style='overflow:hidden'>" % \
        (segment_colors[section.segment], height, height, font_size)
    print "<a href='#%s'>%s</a>" % (sym.name, sym.name)
    print "</td></tr>"
print "</table>"
print "</body></html>"
```

And here's a bad rendering of the HTML it outputs:

[image: Map]

Comment: Thanks. It can be made more accurate by taking into account the 1 pixel gap. Also, you would want to make links in this "map" to some kind of key/dictionary section on the page. But yeah, this could be useful.

Comment: Did you write it. IF so, You wrote this script to answer this question? or you wrote it for your regular use?

Comment: @Frank Krueger, I have never used python before, I just installed the latest version v.3.2 or Windows and was unable to run the above script. Could somebody please fix the script, it is probably just minor issues.

Comment: Doesn't work at all on my map file unfortunately. It doesn't help that the .map format seems to be not very computer-readable.

Comment: This appears to use pre-2.4 version of python.  I tried using it on Python 3.x, had to add parens to the print statements, but then it got hung up on the sort function, using a lambda function where it expected a key argument.  I don't know python & lambdas well enough to progress past that right now.

Comment: @Frank Krueger: amazing piece of code! Could one also extract all this data from the .elf file? Or is it only in the .map file?

Answer (score 8):

I've written a C# program to display the information in a Map file along with information not usually present in the map file (like static symbols provided you can use `binutils`). The code is available [here](https://github.com/govind-mukundan/MapViewer). In short it parses the map file and also uses `BINUTILS` (if available) to gather more information. To run it you need to download the code and run the project under visual studio, browse to the map file path and click `Analyze`.

Note: Only works for `GCC/LD` map files

Screenshot:
[[image: 3]]

Comment: OK I've made some edits. Beyond this, I don't see anything else I can add. *What is this thing you're talking about?* - Self evident - it's a map file parser/viewer. *Where/How do I install it?* - Windows, run project using visual studio *How do I use this thing to solve the exact problem I have in my question?* - Load the map file, run the software *Are you affiliated with this thing in any way, shape, or form?* - Err yeah I wrote it.

Comment: Will this also work with `mono`?

Comment: It might, but I have not tried it. The main external dependency is ObjectListView which according to their [faq](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/html/faq.htm) *mostly works* on Mono.

Comment: Irrespective of others comments, I like this tool.  I have used it several times now and it downloads, builds and just works in seconds!