# Understand a regular expression

Tags: python, c, regex, gcc

I am trying parse a map file that is generated by gcc, for function addresses. There is a possible  [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426/whats-the-best-tool-to-graphically-display-memory-layout-from-a-map-file)(python), but it's not working for me.

I am trying to understand the solution provided. It has got two complex regular expressions..

```
m = re.search('^\[([0-9 ]+)\]\s+(.+)\s*$',line )
m = re.search('^([0-9A-Fx]+)\s+([0-9A-Fx]+)\s+(\[([ 0-9]+)\]|\w+)\s+(.*?)\s*$', line)
```

Can any one explain me what is the RE searching for ?

Is there any other working solution to get function addresses from gcc produced mapfile ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
^\[([0-9 ]+)\]\s+(.+)\s*$

^                  start of the line
\[                 literal [
([0-9 ]+)          group of 0-9 or space, one or more times
\]                 literal ]
\s+                one or more spaces
(.+)               group of anything one or moretimes
\s*                zero or more spaces 
$                  end of line


eg: "[5 5 5] blah"

gives:
    group1 = "5 5 5"
    group2 = blah

^([0-9A-Fx]+)\s+([0-9A-Fx]+)\s+(\[([ 0-9]+)\]|\w+)\s+(.*?)\s*$

^                  start of line
([0-9A-Fx]+)       group of chars one or more times
\s+                one or more spaces
([0-9A-Fx]+)       group of chars one or more times
\s+                one or more spaces
(
    \[             literal [
    ([ 0-9]+)      group of char 1 or more times
    \]             literal [
    |              or
    \w+            word char, one or more times
)
\s+                one or more spaces
(.*?)              any char zero or more times, non greedy
\s*                zero or more spaces
$                  end of line
```

Comment: (It should be noted that the `\s*` at the end will always match nothing, since the `+` in `(.+)` is greedy)

Answer (score 6):

One way to debug Python regular expressions is to use the undocumented re.DEBUG flag when creating a pattern object.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.compile('^\[([0-9 ]+)\]\s+(.+)\s*$', re.DEBUG)
at at_beginning
literal 91
subpattern 1
  max_repeat 1 65535
    in
      range (48, 57)
      literal 32
literal 93
max_repeat 1 65535
  in
    category category_space
subpattern 2
  max_repeat 1 65535
    any None
max_repeat 0 65535
  in
    category category_space
at at_end
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x01CE8950>
```

It's obviously not 100% straightforward to read but it can help if you know a little about how matching works and find the indentation helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
pattern1 = re.compile (
r"""
^                       # start of string
\[                      # literal [
([0-9 ]+)               # Collection of numbers and spaces
\]                      # literal ]
\s+                     # whitespace
(.+)                    # any string of at least one character
\s*                     # possible whitespace
$                       # end of string
""", re.VERBOSE )

pattern2 = re.compile (
r"""
^                       # Start of string
([0-9A-Fx]+)            # Collection of hexadecimal digits or 'x'
\s+                     # Whitespace
([0-9A-Fx]+)            # Collection of hexadecimal digits or 'x'
\s+                     # Whitespace
(\[([ 0-9]+)\]|\w+)     # A collection of numbers, or space, inside [] brackets
\s+                     # Whitespace
(.*?)                   # Any string
\s*                     # Possible whitespace
$                       # End of string
""", re.VERBOSE)
```

These are actually quite badly written regular expressions.

I'll bet that the `([0-9A-Fx]+)` subgroups are actually meant to match hexadecimal numbers, like `0x1234DEADBEEF`. The way they're written, though, they could match absurdities like `xxxxxxxxxx` as well. `0x[0-9A-F]+` would be more appropriate here.

There's also the use of a non-greedy match `(.*?)` in the second regex which will be forced to be greedy anyway, since the regex must match an entire line.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is:

```
^         start of string
\[        a '['
([0-9 ]+) one or more digits and spaces
\]        a ']'
\s+       whitespace
(.+)      anything
\s*       optional whitespace
$         end of string
```

Examples:

```
"[12345] Hello"
"[06 7] \t Foo.Bar!  "
```

The second one is:

```
^            start of string
([0-9A-Fx]+) hex digits and x
\s+          whitespace
([0-9A-Fx]+) hex digits and x
\s+          whitespace
(            either:
\[             a '['
([ 0-9]+)      digits and spaces
\]             a ']'
|            or:
\w+            a word
)            end group
\s+          whitespace
(.*?)        optional anything (non-greedy)
\s*          optional whitespace
$            end string
```

Examples:

```
"0xF00 0x1234 [89] Foo"
"78x9 023 Foobar "
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an invaluable link to figure out these regex expressions.

[Click on this](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5E%5C%5B%28%5B0-9%20%5D%2b%29%5C%5D%5Cs%2b%28.%2b%29%5Cs%2a%24)

You first regex will be parsed and explained as:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9 ]+                  any character of: '0' to '9', ' ' (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \]                       ']'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

I assume you can figure out how to get the second one parsed.

Cheers.